# iPhone Swipe Gesture crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app that I'd like the swipe gesture to flip to a second view. The app is all set up with buttons that work. The swipe gesture though causes a crash ( “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.).

The gesture code is:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    switch (recognizer.direction)
    {
        case (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight):
            [self performSelector:@selector(flipper:)];
            break;

        case (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft): 
            [self performSelector:@selector(flipper:)];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }   
}

and "flipper" looks like this:


- (IBAction)flipper:(id)sender {
    FlashCardsAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (FlashCardsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [mainDelegate flipToFront];
}
```

flipToBack (and flipToFront) look like this..

```
- (void)flipToBack {
     NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    BackViewController *theBackView = [[BackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BackView" bundle:nil];
    [self setBackViewController:theBackView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:window cache:YES];
    [frontViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[backViewController view]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [frontViewController release];
    frontViewController = nil;
    [theBackView release];
    //  NSLog (@" FINISHED ");
}
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way... All ideas are welcome...

Comment: Please let us know what line it crashed on as well as what the debugger says when it crashes. Also when you say the buttons work, does that mean you have buttons that call the flip methods as well as calling it from a gesture recognizer?

Comment: Carl, I think we cross posted, but it was crashing on the device at the line:  [frontViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you even using `performSelector:` Just because a method is marked as an `(IBAction)` doesn't make it any different from any other method, and you can send them as messages to a class instance

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if ((recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) || (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)) {
        [self flipper:nil]
    }
}
```

Actually, since the gesture directions are just bit flags this can be written as:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (recognizer.direction & (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)) {
        [self flipper:nil]
    }
}
```

Comment: Great... Many thanks to Abizem and Jacob. I knew there was a better way to do this. I found though, that I needed to remove the line:  [frontViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 2):

Your selector needs to take an argument as implied by the `:` character in the name, so you should use [`performSelector:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCFACCF).

```
[self performSelector:@selector(flipper:) withObject:nil];
```